# Histogram with normal curve for Larger Dataset

Tags: r, histogram

I am new to R and I am trying to plot a histogram for the following numbers

Input.txt

```
a b c 1.111 
d e f 2.3433 
g h i 9.87667 
............ 
............
```

Total records - 2444910

Maximum value - 142701.38999976

So, far I have tried this

```
setwd ("/path/")
data <- read.table ("input.txt", sep="\t", header=F)
x <-data$V4
bins = seq(0,150000,by=10000)
h <- hist(x, breaks=bins, probability=TRUE)
s = sd(x)
m = mean(x)
curve(dnorm(x, mean=m, sd=s), add=TRUE, lwd=3, col="red")
lines(density(x), col="blue")
abline(v=mean(x),col="blue")
mtext(paste("mean ", round(mean(x),1), "; sd ", round(sd(x),1), "; N ",length(x),sep=""), side=1, cex=.75)
dev.off()
```

But, all I could get a single histogram bar near to the (0,0) coordinate. Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: did you check `typeof(data$V4)` (or `is.numeric(data$V4)`) to be sure it's still numeric?  Did you make sure that more than one value is greater than your first bin value of 10 000?  take a look at the value of `m` and `median(x)` as well, maybe.

Comment: Do this: `table(cut(data$V4, bins))` , .... I'm guessing you are getting a correct result that you did not expect.

Comment: My first value starts at 2.1111775 and the final value is the maximum value I have posted in my question.

Comment: @Dwin - Where do I add table(cut(data$V4, bins)) in my code. Sorry I am new to R. I am pretty much sure that the bins count is driving me crazy.

The x-axis in my output image is like this 0-50000-100000-150000.

My Y-axis has the density values ranging from o till 5e-04.

Thanks

Comment: @Carl. I tried typeof(data$V4). It says the values are double. Is that making any difference?

Comment: Just type the code at the console prompt. The point is that almost of your data will be in the first bin. You don't seem to get that yet.

Comment: Make a `boxplot()` to investigate if those high values are just outliers, which you could possibly exclude from the histogram. Normally it is not necessary to define breaks manually for `hist()`.

Comment: @DWin - you got it right. Most of the data falls below 10000 bins. And the only record above 100K is the maximum value record with a value 142701. The interval points on my x-axis starts at 0 with 50000 interval. So, all I see is 0, 50000, 100000 and 150000. My question now is how do I change the axes so that the interval points are at 100 and after 10000, the interval changes to 1000 till 150000?

Comment: Hey, I got it right first! :-).  But to solve your hist problem, either remove the values as `newdata<-data$V4[data$V4<1e5]` or read the documentation on `hist` as to how to specify the bin intervals and range.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- data.frame(V4=c(runif(10000, 1,5000), 149999))
hist(dat$V4, breaks=c(seq(0,5000,100), 150000) )
```

To exclude outliers:

```
hist(dat$V4[dat$V4 <5000], breaks=c(seq(0,5000,100)) )
```

Comment: It still generates the same plot DWin. No luck. :(

Comment: Well, I tested it with the example above and it returns the expected result. If you do not like those results, you need to modify your data by excluding the outlier.

Comment: Thanks DWin. Can you tell me how to exclude the outliers in my dataset?

Thanks for your time.